# Remove number from list if the first digit and length are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list of `[100, 210, 250, 300, 405, 430, 500, 1850, 1875, 2120, 2150]`
I want to remove any numbers that start with the same digit and have the same length.
The result should be:  `[100, 210, 300, 405, 500, 1850, 2120]`

What I have so far is:

```
for i in installed_tx_calc:
    if (len(str(i)) == 3) and (str(i)[:1] == str(i-1)[:1]):
        installed_tx_calc.remove(i)
    elif str(i)[:2] == str(i-1)[:2]:
        installed_tx_calc.remove(i)
```

I have a list of `[862, 1930, 2496]` and my code outputs `[1930]`.

I couldn't find anything when searching, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How do you choose which number to keep?  For instance, does it matter whether you remove 210 or 250?

Comment: first come first i think

Comment: Also, is it guaranteed that this list is sorted?

Comment: Yes, the list is always from lowest to highest.  I want to keep the lower number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the new list with a list comprehension, using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

numbers =  [100, 210, 250, 300, 405, 430, 500, 1850, 1875, 2120, 2150]

out = [next(group) for key, group in groupby(numbers, key=lambda n: (str(n)[0], len(str(n))))]

print(out)
# [100, 210, 300, 405, 500, 1850, 2120]
```

We group using the tuple (first digit, length of number), and keep the first number of each group, which we get with `next(group)`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new set that will keep unique entries. Then, you may filter according to that set:

```
unique = set()
mylist = [100, 210, 250, 300, 405, 430, 500, 1850, 1875, 2120, 2150]
newlist = []

for num in mylist:
    num_str = str(num)
    length = len(num_str)
    first_digit = num_str[0]
    if (length, first_digit) in unique:
        continue
    newlist.append(num)
    unique.add((length, first_digit))

>>> newlist
[100, 210, 300, 405, 500, 1850, 2120]
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you are using the variable `i` as a string in `installed_tx_calc`.  However, you can't subtract from a string. What you really want is to use `i` as an index and access in this way: `installed_tx_calc[i]`.  However, using the index can be tricky if you are removing items from the list, so I've replaced the for loop with a while loop.  Also, I would recommend that you access the first digit directly, instead of getting a slice.  Therefore, your code will look more like this:

```
i = 1
while i < len(installed_tx_calc):
    if len(str(installed_tx_calc[i]) == 3 and str(installed_tx_calc[i])[0] == str(installed_tx_calc[i-1])[0]:
        installed_tx_calc.remove(i)
        continue
    elif str(installed_tx_calc[i])[0] == str(installed_tx_calc[i-1])[0]:
        installed_tx_calc.remove(i)
        continue
    i += 1
```

Keep in mind that this will break if you have more numbers of length not equal to 3 or 4.  A more extensible solution would be:

```
i = 1
while i < len(installed_tx_calc):
    if len(str(installed_tx_calc[i])) == len(str(installed_tx_calc[i-1])) and str(installed_tx_calc[i])[0] == str(installed_tx_calc[i-1])[0]:
        installed_tx_calc.remove(i)
        continue
    i += 1
```

A final optimization would be to avoid using `remove` in favor of building a new list.  `remove` can be a fairly slow operation compared to `append` so the following will be faster than the previous two solutions:

```
new_itc = []
for i in range(1, len(installed_tx_calc):
    if not (len(str(installed_tx_calc[i])) == len(str(installed_tx_calc[i-1])) and str(installed_tx_calc[i])[0] == str(installed_tx_calc[i-1])[0]):
        new_itc.append(installed_tx_calc[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the list from low value to high values. Check on the highest base of the number (so for 350, this is 100) and if a multiple of this base (i.e. 3) has not occurred before then add this value to a new list

```
a_list = [210, 100, 250, 300, 405, 430, 500, 1850, 1875, 2120, 2150]
a_list.sort()
new_list = []
base = 1
pre_multiple = 0

for value in a_list:
    while (value / base ) >= 10:
        base *= 10

    multiple = int(value/base)
    if multiple != pre_multiple:
        new_list.append(value)

    pre_multiple = multiple

print(new_list)
```